# How to read field in another view in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i m in elements/navigation.ctp , in the navbar i put a condition if :

```
<li class="dropdown"> 

    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-bell">
            <?php 
            //$this->loadModel("Location");
            if($this->Session->read('auth.Location.status')==0):
            echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="color:red;">
            </span>';
            ?>

            <?php endif;?>
        </i>
        <b class="caret">
        </b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="label label-danger">Notificaion</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">View All</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

i went when the field status in Location table is == 0 it displays a notification icon, and when it is 1 it shows nothing, but the problem i think that i have put the false code , 
Help :'(

Comment: Where you set up session variable `$this->Session->read('auth.Location.status')`? Could you show code?

Comment: how to set location in session variable?  I have not written anything

Comment: this is session.php : 



class SessionsSchema extends CakeSchema {

 public $name = 'Sessions';

 public function before($event = array()) {
  return true;
 }

 public function after($event = array()) {
 }

 public $cake_sessions = array(
  'id' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false, 'key' => 'primary'),
  'data' => array('type' => 'text', 'null' => true, 'default' => null),
  'expires' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => true, 'default' => null),
  'indexes' => array('PRIMARY' => array('column' => 'id', 'unique' => 1))
 );

}